# Another double integration

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

I am wondering if there is a way to proceed with the following integral analytically $$\int_0^1 dx \int_0^{{1-x}} dy \frac{1}{A+B},$$ where $$A = a(x^2-y^2-b(x^2+y^2)+b(x+y)+y-x+2bxy)$$ and $$B = c(x^2-y^2-x+y-b(x+y)),$$ with $a,b,c$ are constants. I made the transformations $u=y-x$ and $v=y+x$ and this puts the integrand into the form $$\frac{1}{2}\int_0^1 dv \int_{-v}^v du \frac{1}{(u-uv)a + vb - u^2c},$$ together with the new parametrisation of domain.  This at a glance certainly looks more tractable and I think it would be best to proceed by interchanging order of integration because of the term quadratic in $u$ but the resulting logs I get do not allow for an easy evaluation of the $u$ integral, as far as I can see.

Does anyone have further insights so I may progress with this at an analytic level?

Comment: It might be helpful to know if there are any conditions on the parameters $(a,b,c)$. May we at least assume they are real numbers?

Comment: @David H yes they stand for variables external to the integration and are real valued. Thanks